# ArrayList thinks its empty in certain methods

Tags: java

Um so for some reason everything besides add() and RemoveMovie() think the arraylists are empty. Why? And how can I fix this without removing the arraylists. My entire program kinda revolves around these being arraylists that's why... And I just don't understand how this can happen

```
    //bunch O info
    private ArrayList<String> movieName=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> movieDes=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> movieDate=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> movieAdult=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> movieLanguage=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> movieID=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> moviePopularity=new ArrayList<>();

    public void add (JsonObject movieJ)
    {
        //Add thine info
        movieName.add(movieJ.get("title").toString());
        movieDes.add(movieJ.get("overview").toString());
        movieDate.add(movieJ.get("release_date").toString());
        movieAdult.add(movieJ.get("adult").toString());
        movieLanguage.add(movieJ.get("original_language").toString());
        movieID.add(movieJ.get("id").toString());
        moviePopularity.add(movieJ.get("popularity").toString());

        System.out.println(movieDate);
        //System.out.println(movieID);
        System.out.println(moviePopularity);
        System.out.println(movieAdult);
        //System.out.println(movieName);
    }
    public void RemoveMovie(int id)
    {
        //Execute(Delete) thee info
        movieName.remove(id);
        movieDes.remove(id);
        movieDate.remove(id);
        movieAdult.remove(id);
        movieLanguage.remove(id);
        movieID.remove(id);
        moviePopularity.remove(id);
    }

    public String GetRating(int id)
    {
        System.out.println(moviePopularity);

        if(movieName.isEmpty())
            return "Nothing Found!";
        else
            return moviePopularity.get(id);
    }
    public String MovieAdult(int id)
    {
        if(movieName.isEmpty())
            return "Nothing Found!";
        else
            return movieAdult.get(id);
    }
    public String GetDate(int id)
    {
        if(movieName.isEmpty())
            return "Nothing Found!";
        else
            return movieDate.get(id).replace("\"","");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "think the arraylists are empty", does it print "Nothing Found!" or does it return `null`?

Comment: in the println it prints [] otherwise yes it returns nothing found

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using the `index` or the `object` equivalent what List contains, So as you remove with int the remove method will remove the object at the position of `id`, what you need to get the index of an object from `movieID` the remove from other at the same id

Like this:

```
    public void RemoveMovie(int id) {
       int index = movieID.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(id));      
        movieName.remove(index);
        movieDes.remove(index);
        movieDate.remove(index);
        movieAdult.remove(index);
        movieLanguage.remove(index);
        movieID.remove(index);
        moviePopularity.remove(index);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks? but RemoveMovie() and add() are fine its the other methods that cant find whats stored in the arraylists